# Why don't non-GTK apps get Gnome's mouse cursor size setting?

Tags: gnome, mouse, wayland

I am using Gnome 43.4, Wayland. I have set a large cursor size in Gnome Settings -> Accessibility. Above the desktop and GTK apps, the mouse cursor size is what I set, but above non-GTK apps, such as QT apps, the mouse cursor becomes small.

I have figured out that if I manually set `XCURSOR_SIZE` in a config file in `environment.d`, then non-GTK apps use that cursor size. But this is a awkward way for an end-user. I wonder why setting the larger cursor in the Settings GUI doesn't just work. Who is to blame? Is it...

1. No one's fault: There is no standard universal way in Linux to set mouse cursor size.
2. Those apps' fault: They did not respect the mouse cursor size set by Gnome.
3. Gnome's fault: It sets the mouse cursor size in a non-standard way
4. My fault: I set the mouse cursor size in a wrong way.
5. Someone else's fault

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Someone else's fault

Wayland didn't standardize that. Just as it didn't specify how an application could communicate a window icon, another accessibility feature in perfectly abundant use by X11 applications.

Comment: I wonder what the Wayland developers were thinking. Since they started later than X11, they should have seen such things in X11 and known that such things are needed. Then, why didn't they standardise those?